# Path planning or 2D Mapping

Tags: mapping, path-planning, opencv

i want to collect some ideas about this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-ZDB8xqI7M 
Is the Left Vacuum cleaner using some 2D Mapping or OpenCV to navigate through the room ?
Or is it just a Hard coded Algorithm to do the path planning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left one has LiDAR and it does 2D SLAM. OpenCV is an image processing library not a tool for robot navigation. The path is planned in the onboard embedded system based on the built map.

Comment: ty, do you know which mcu family is able to do 2D Slam?